# Loading text file data

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, filereader, stringbuilder

I have a problem with reading from a text file created by my application. My app generates a text file which contains data for one field in every line but even with answers for BufferedReader and StringBuilder. I can't handle it well on many combinations. Load button is supposed to load name of the file (and does it) and to write data in specified fields (TextView). Why it does not work? At start I thought it was a problem with StringBuilder because it showed me kind of an error about not reading data from the file so I made that it doesn't produce this error anymore but still nothing.

onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent Data) {

    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, Data);

    if (reqCode == reqGaleria) {

        if (resCode == RESULT_OK) {

            try {

                Uri imageUri = Data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                ramka.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                sciezka = imageUri.getPath();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coś poszło nie tak", LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nie wybrałeś obrazu", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    if (reqCode == reqLoad) {

        if (resCode == RESULT_OK) {

            try {

                Uri plik = Data.getData();
                @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor kursor = getContentResolver().query(plik, null, null, null, null);

                int nazwa_i = kursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                kursor.moveToFirst();//Musi zostać - bez tego nie wyskoczy nazwa pliku
                wczytaj.setText(kursor.getString(nazwa_i));

                FileReader test = new FileReader(String.valueOf(wczytaj));
                BufferedReader bufor_w = new BufferedReader(test);
                String line;
                line = bufor_w.readLine();
                StringBuilder bob = new StringBuilder(line);

                i_e_magazyn.setText(bob);

                bob.append('\n');

                i_e_strefa.setText(bob);

                bufor_w.close();
                kursor.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Problem z uruchamianiem pliku",
                        LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nie wybrałeś pliku", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Button that is responsible for loading.

```
 b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
           intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
           intent.setType("text/*");
           startActivityForResult(intent,reqLoad);
       }
    });
```

File:

```
Magazyn
Strefa
Rząd
Rama
Słup
Uszkodzenie
Wielkość Uszkodzenia
Lokalizacja
Zielony
Dalsze Działania
Potrzebne Elementy
Typ Elementu
666
/external/images/media/68
```

Last line is path to image that is loaded

Edit:
Problem is not by just reading the file but to read the file that I choose.
When I specify the file which has to be loaded, it loads perfectly. When I decide to show him from which file it have to load data, tells me that file doesn't exist.

Code that works:

```
testowy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

           File pliczek = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
           File plik = new File(pliczek,"/est.txt");
           StringBuilder string;
           string = new StringBuilder();

           try{

               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(plik));
               String linia;
               int licz = 0;

               while((linia = reader.readLine())!=null){

                   switch(licz) {

                       case 0:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_magazyn.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                       case 1:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_strefa.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 2:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_rzad.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 3:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_rama.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 4:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_slup.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 5:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_uszk.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 6:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_w_uszk.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 7:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_lok.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 8:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_klasa.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 9:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_dal_dzial.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 10:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_pot_elem.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 11:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_typ.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 12:
                           string.append(linia);
                           i_e_ilosc.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                       case 13:
                           string.append(linia);
                           wczytaj.setText(linia);
                           string.append('\n');
                           break;

                   }

                   licz++;

               }

           } catch(FileNotFoundException e){

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nie ma takiego pliku",LENGTH_SHORT)
                       .show();

           } catch(IOException e){

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nie zczytano pliku",LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }

       }

    });
```

Code adapted to choose a file:

```
if (reqCode == reqLoad) {

        if (resCode == RESULT_OK) {


            Uri wskaznik = data.getData();

            assert wskaznik != null;

            //FileReader test = new FileReader(Data.getData().toString());
            edytuj.setText(String.valueOf(wskaznik));
            File pliczek = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File plik = new File(String.valueOf(wskaznik));
            StringBuilder string;
            string = new StringBuilder();

            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(plik));
                String linia;
                int licz = 0;

                while ((linia = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    switch (licz) {

                        case 0:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_magazyn.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_strefa.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_rzad.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_rama.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_slup.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_uszk.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 6:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_w_uszk.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 7:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_lok.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 8:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_klasa.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 9:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_dal_dzial.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 10:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_pot_elem.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 11:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_typ.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 12:
                            string.append(linia);
                            i_e_ilosc.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                        case 13:
                            string.append(linia);
                            wczytaj.setText(linia);
                            string.append('\n');
                            break;

                    }

                    licz++;

                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nie ma takiego pliku",
                        LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nie zczytano pliku", LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nie wybrałeś pliku", LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could post the input file? One thing that might be wrong is that you say "_My app generates a text file wich contains data for one field in every line_", but you only perform one `readLine()` with your `BufferedReader`. I'm assuming you'll need to read more than just one line, but I can't be sure without seeing your input.

Comment: @FrancisBartkowiak isn't it supposed to load as much data as i define and close when i define to close?

Comment: Yes. But you only define it to load one line. If your input file has multiple lines in it (i.e. L1, L2, L3, ..., LN), you're only reading L1. All your `StringBuilder` does is get that first line added to it, and then a new line character (the "\n"). I'm assuming what you actually want to do to is obtain every line in the file and do something with each line. Again, I can't be sure without seeing your input.

Comment: `FileReader test = new FileReader(String.valueOf(wczytaj));`. Change to `FileReader test = new FileReader(Data.getData());`. And remove the Cursor stuff.

Comment: @greenapps Cannot resolve constructor 'FileReader(android.net.Uri)' :(

Comment: Sorry: `FileReader(Data.getData().toString());`. And hopefully FileReader can read from a content scheme and does not expect a file path only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a `StringBuilder` at all. I think you want to read in each line of the file and assign each line to a different field depending on which line you're on in the file. If that is the case, one way you could read in the file would be like this:

```
FileReader test = new FileReader(Data.getData().toString());
BufferedReader bufor_w = new BufferedReader(test);
String line;
int counter = 0;
while((line = bufor_w.readLine()) != null){
    switch(counter){
        case 0:
            i_e_magazyn.setText(line);
            break;
        case 1:
            i_e_strefa.setText(line);
            break;
        case 2:
            //etc.
            break;
    }
    counter++;
}
bufor_w.close();
test.close();
```

This will read in each line of the file and depending on which line you're on, you can assign the value to whatever field you like.

Comment: will it work for loading a file from path contained in file?

Comment: Once you get to that line (looks to be 13), you can do whatever you'd like with that `String`. So if you wanted to read that line and then open the file that it points to, you could.

Comment: Unfortunately still show error from catch. Android studio shows that toString can cause nullpointerexception

Comment: 01-31 14:19:42.402 1916-1916/? D/Documents: onFinished() [content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ATest.txt]
01-31 14:19:42.553 1916-1935/? D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb4bd9480 (ListView) with handle 0xb4b91cd0

Comment: I found that the problem is that BufferedReader is losing file i point him to load. FileNotFoundExpection is catched.